# How can I set the syntax colour inside delimiters in Emacs?

Tags: python, html, emacs, web2py

I have a HTML file, and I’m using python code inside curly braces (web2py templates), something like

```
{{for i in range something:}}
{{=i.name}}
{{pass}}
```

inside the body of a file with a .html extension.

My question is, How can I change the colour of the code inside the `{{}}` delimiters? The delimiters have a different colour with rainbow-delimiters and also I have auto-pair, but what I’d really like to have is a custom colour for the python code inside delimiters within the .html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[web-mode.el](http://web-mode.org) is now compatible with web2py

Comment: testing it right now, hope works fine with python code inside html files. thaks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This is a common request. It is not easy to do in Emacs unfortunately. Look here for some options [Multiple modes on Emacs Wiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes). BTW, if you have never looked around it the Emacs Wiki has LOTS of useful info.

Answer (score 0):

After a few months i have to say thanks to @sean perry for the hint, finally i found out what i needed, i'm not an emacs expert but here is my solution:

First downloaded [multi-web-mode](http://github.com/fgallina/multi-web-mode)

then as the set up steps say added this to my init.el:

```
(require 'multi-web-mode)
(setq mweb-default-major-mode 'html-mode)
(setq mweb-tags '((php-mode "<\\?php\\|<\\? \\|<\\?=" "\\?>")
              (js-mode "<script +\\(type=\"text/javascript\"\\|language=\"javascript\"\\)[^>]*>" "</script>")
              (css-mode "<style +type=\"text/css\"[^>]*>" "</style>")))
(setq mweb-filename-extensions '("php" "htm" "html" "ctp" "phtml" "php4" "php5"))
(multi-web-global-mode 1)
```

finally after css-mode added this line:

```
(python-mode "{{" "}}")
```

and now the python code between {{ }} in web2py's templates is correctly highlighted.